Transaction rollback in integration test does not work properly in multi-threaded mode
I used this trick for Integration tests to ensures that each test is ran in a transaction and this transaction is rolled back:
I defined following base class and all my integration test classes can inherit from it.
public abstract class IntegrationTestBase
{
   private TransactionScope scope;

   [TestInitialize]
   public void TestInitialize()
   {
      scope = new TransactionScope();
   }

   [TestCleanup]
   public void TestCleanup()
   {
     scope.Dispose();
   }
}

It works but not for following code:
 [TestMethod]
 public void SaveTwoDocumentsSimultaneously_WorkSuccessfully()
 {
    //Assign

    var doc1 = new Document() { Number = "Test-1" };
    var doc2 = new Document() { Number = "Test-2" };

   //Action
   Parallel.Invoke(() => SaveNewDocument(doc1), () => SaveNewDocument(doc2));
   //Assert
   Assert.IsTrue(true);
}
void SaveNewDocument(Document doc)
{
   using (var ctx = new MyDbContext())
   {
      ctx.Documents.Add(doc);
      ctx.SaveChanges();
   }
}

When the test is passed, there is a record number Test-2 in the database, in other words, the transaction has not been rolled back as I expect(I expect There is no record with numbers Test-1 and Test-2 in the database).
I think I should use DependentTransaction according this link.
How can I use the Transaction that opened in IntegrationTestBase(using TransactionScope) and to use it as parent Transaction?

this question seems like a good start

I'm not fully familiar with this specific issue but could this be related to TransactionScope beeing tied to a single thread while Paralell.Invoke  executes across multiple threads which may not have a reference to the transaction scope?
I found this documentation which seems to indicate the transaction scope can be configured for multiple threads using TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.transactions.transactionscope.-ctor?view=net-8.0#system-transactions-transactionscope-ctor(system-transactions-transactionscopeasyncflowoption)

If you are using EF you should probably follow the documented approach to create transactions

You restated the question. Did you see the answer in the duplicate question? It tells you what to do in an async scenario.

@GertArnold: Yes, but I asked how can I access a transaction that created in base class, to use it via DependentTransaction.

Well, using this TransactionScopeAsyncFlowOption.Enabled should do the trick.

You simply can't use concurrency using one connection to DB. A single connection works synchronously, and if you try to make queries in parallel using one connection, that would lead to unpredictable behavior. Instead, if u want to query DB in parallel, create different connections and use them concurrently.
Bottom-line: one connection allows one query at a time.
PS and due to the fact that u can query DB only synchronously using one connection, you surely can't use concurrency within a single transaction, because single transaction belongs to single connection

This is not true. It's perfectly possible to do parallel queries in EF (ADO.Net), because the runtime manages the physical connections from the connection pool. The only thing is that the same context instance shouldn't be used in parallel threads.
